# Row selection limit (?) VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am new in VBA.

I run into a problem and I could not find any answer using google. The goal is: selecting multiple rows, then deleting them. Here is the code:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim SelectedCells As String

i = 1
SelectedCells = ""

While IsEmpty(Range("A" & i)) = False

If Range("A" & i) < 5 Then

        SelectedCells = SelectedCells & i & ":" & i & ","
        i = i + 1
Else:
        i = i + 1
End If

Wend

SelectedCells = Left(SelectedCells, Len(SelectedCells) - 1)
'That is how I inspected the value of the "SelectedCells" variable:
'Range("AA1").Value = Right(SelectedCells, 25)
Range(SelectedCells).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

It works fine up to 45 selections. If it needs to select more than that, it returns an error message at the "Range(SelectedCells).Select":
"Run-time error '1004':
Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed.

However, I inspected the value of SelectedCells variable, and it looks as it should...

Does anybody have an idea what is wrong? Do you have any better idea to solve this issue? I need to run this kind of loop on several thousands (or hundred-thousands) of records.

Any input will be appriciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SelectedCells is a string (max 256 in length), so it just happens to be 45 selections. instead, use a loop like :

ok , this will boost the speed of your stuff, even if its a bit more complicated
(PS: dont use select, unless you want to select as a final goal)
(PS2: Code not tested, adjust to your needs)

```
Dim ColA() as variant 'declares variable of VBA Array (wich is faster than Excel Array)
Dim i as long , MaxData as Long
Dim Sh as Worksheet

With Application
    .screenupdating=false
    .enableevents=false
    .calculation=XlManual
End with

Set Sh = Activesheet 'for multiple sheets just add sh in an argument when calling the macro
with sh
    MaxData = .cells( .rows.count , "A").End(Xlup).row 'count the lines in Column A
    redim ColA (1 to maxData , 1 to 1)
    ColA = .range( .cells(1,1) , .cells( MaxData,1) ).value 'ok, you can write this .range("A1:A" & maxData).value , also

    Dim Temp as Variant

    For i=MaxData to  step -1 'if you go the other way, some lines will be forgotten
        temp = ColA(i,1)
        if isempty(temp) then 
            exit for
        Elseif Temp<5 then .Cells(i,1).EntireRow.delete 'can be written many other ways, dont use select ; might need a if isnumber(Temp) or if isnumeric(Temp) to avoid text, but i used temp as variant to settle this
        'a simple .rows(i).delete , might just do the trick :)
        'also an other way : instead of adding the line number (i) to a string , you can increment a variable array ToDelete(1)=line1, Todelelte(2)=line28 ...
        'in my example of code i delete right away...
        End if
    Next i

erase ColA
set sh=nothing

With Application
    .screenupdating=true
    .enableevents=true
    .calculation=XlAutomatic
End with
```

Comment: Patrick! This is a really great solution! Many thanks for it!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to select the range before deleting it. You do not have to use cell addresses.

```
' Get a reference to sheet
Dim s As Worksheet
Set s = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
' Get reference of range including row n to m
Dim n As Integer
Dim m As Integer
n = 10
m = 29
Dim r As Range
Set r = s.Range (s.Rows (n), s.Rows (m))
r.Delete
```

Comment: Thank you Tarik. n and m are not known in my case. The selection is based on the if condition. Since I have several thousands of single selections, I need to collect the indexes of the selected rows in a variable. Then I use the Range(n:n,m:m,etc:etc) selection. It seems I need to select them first, then delete them. I tried delete them right away in the while loop, but it takes forever with several hundreds of thousands of records...

Comment: You can still create a range object having several areas and delete the whole range without selecting. It seems to me that you are using Excel as a sort of database which is not a very good idea. Use Access or any other DB.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
Range("10:100").Delete
```

or

```
Range(n & ":" & m).Delete
```

Comment: Thank you Stenci. That is what I used here. Unfortunately I have thousands of single selections using this while loop... The selection is based on the if condition. The code what I use (and the Range(2:2, 3:3, 4:4, etc:etc) cannot handle more than 45 single selections...

Comment: Then you can make a cycle that deletes one selection at a time. If it's too slow you can: (1) start with `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and end with `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` and (2) start the cycle from the bottom of the sheet and go up (so when you delete the rows on the top there is less shifting going on)

Comment: Thank you Stenci. Your suggested method reduced the processing time to the half of the original's.